# Array of strings not converted to arrays of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm trying to understand the following behaviour:

```
irb(main):016:0* pg = ProductGroup.find(1)
irb(main):017:0> pg.good_type_ids
=> [1]
irb(main):018:0> pg.update({"good_type_ids"=>["", "1"]})
irb(main):019:0> pg.changed?
=> false
irb(main):020:0> pg.good_type_ids
=> ["1"]
```

The code above mimics a form update. The good_type_ids are selected ids's of a multi select. Although the value of the array changes from [1] to ["1"], the changed? method returns false. The update method seems also be smart enough to strip the empty string.

```
irb(main):021:0> pg = ProductGroup.find(1)
irb(main):022:0> pg.good_type_ids
=> [1]
irb(main):023:0> pg.attributes = {"good_type_ids"=>["", "1"]}
=> {"good_type_ids"=>["", "1"]}
irb(main):024:0> pg.changed?
=> true
irb(main):025:0> pg.good_type_ids
=> ["", "1"]
```

In this second example I'm trying to apply the changed params from the form to the object. I don't want to save it to the dbs!
Somehow the attributes method behaves different than the update method and good_type_ids will be ["","1"] after the method was invoked.

It seems that the type of the column in the dbs is taken into account by the "update" and "attributes" method, only for arrays (postgress) this doesn't seem to work.

```
irb(main):030:0* pg.attributes = {"recourse_days"=>5}
=> {"recourse_days"=>5}
irb(main):031:0> pg.changed?
=> true
irb(main):039:0* pg.recourse_days
=> 5
```

recourse_days are defined as integer, during post the controller receives a string and converts it correctly to an integer.

Schema.rb: t.integer  "good_type_ids",        default: [], array: true

As temporary work arround I have put this in the update method of the controller

```
params["good_type_ids"].reject!(&:blank?)
params["good_type_ids"].map!(&:to_i)
```

Comment: What kind of method is `good_type_ids`?  Is it from a has_many association, or is it a serialized field?  (or something else?)  What type of column is it in your database?  What actually gets stored in the database when you view it in the sql console?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?  "Array" is a column type in Postgres.  This means that instead of Rails handling the conversion, your actual DBMS is doing it, and it's this behaviour that you are seeing.  see https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja/rails-4-the-postgresql-array-data-type

Comment: good_type_ids can be seen as a getter/setter.  
Schema.rb: t.integer "good_type_ids", default: [], array: true  
  
The bevior gets stranger.    
  
In dbs the value of good_type_ids is {1}.  
Rails console:  
`pg = Product.find(1)`  
 `pg.attributes = {"good_type_ids"=>["", "2"]}`  
`pg.good_type_ids`  
`=> ["", "2"]``  
`pg.save`  
`pg.good_type_ids`  
`=> ["2"]`  
  
In the DBS  however the value is saved correct, it's {2}  
I found out that when I do pg.reload the array of strings becomes an array of integers.
`pg.reload`  
`pg.good_type_ids`  
`=> [2]`

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, I'm using the PostgreSQL "Array" column type. I expected active record to do the conversion. Probably I expected too much from this specific Array implementation for PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you want ActiveRecord to do the conversion, then make it a `TEXT` column instead and serialize the field into an array in your model definition like `serialize :good_type_ids, Array`

Answer (score -1):

**UPD**

Strings conversion issues and nil elements saving to pgsql seems to be fixed in rails 4.2.0, i've heard whole type casting system is pretty much revised there:

```
> doc.test_digit = ["1"] #=> ["1"] 
> doc.test_digit #=> [1] 
> doc.test_string #=> ["2"] 
> doc.test_string = [2] #=> [2] 
> doc.test_string #=> ["2"]
>   doc.attributes = {'test_digit'=>["", "2"]}
 => {"test_digit"=>["", "2"]} 
> doc.test_digit #=> [nil, 2] 
> doc.save
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE "documents" SET "test_digit" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "documents"."id" = $3  [["test_digit", "{NULL,2}"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-26 00:32:25.326735"], ["id", 1]]
   (3.7ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
> doc.reload 
  Document Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Document id: 1, name: "test1", test_digit: [nil, 2], test_string: ["2"], created_at: "2015-02-25 23:51:32", updated_at: "2015-02-26 00:32:25"> 

> doc.test_digit #=> [nil, 2]
```

I used following migrations:

```
t.integer :test_digit, array: true, default: []
t.string :test_string, array: true, default: []
```

---

Update method updates the db, thus your model attributes are no longer dirty.

[Good guide on this](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

> The update method seems also be smart enough to strip the empty string.

This is not normal behavior, according to the source of pgsql adapter/array_parser, empty array elements should be saved and loaded as any other values. (this functionality was added on [Aug 20, 2012](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4544d2bc90bea93c38bb21d912dba00f51cf620f) to the adapter just in case you are using an older version)